# Regex expression to match word in a string

Tags: regex, xml, regex-group

I've been banging my head with this issue as I can't get this expression to work.

I'm trying to match and output a specific word from a string, so for example, take this string:

```
<ANIMALS>
<value>DOG CAT COW</value>
</ANIMALS>
```

And now I want to match any one of them and return that value otherwise none, let's say, COW.
I've tried a lot of varying expressions with no luck such as:

```
IF(VALUE == "/(^|\W)COW($|\W)/", "COWVALUE", "NONE")
```

This doesn't work, nor do any other variants I've tried. If I keep the original string as a single word and no actual calling expression, just a word, then it always works. As soon as I introduce a string of words then I can't make it happen.

Could anyone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language is that?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `(^|\W)` and `($|\W)`, since that only matches at word boundaries, but you want to match `COW` when it's not by itself as a word. The regular expression should just be `/COW/`, it will match that string wherever it appears in the string.

BTW, to match word boundaries you can use `\b` rather than those alternations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what programming language you're using but following is a simple example based in Javascript to do achieve your goals.
[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA5FZW/7)